# function returning reference to a vector element

Tags: c++, reference, stdvector

I cannot figure out how to return a reference to a vector element. The [] and at() are returning reference, no?

But when I try the following, it won't compile.

I'm using Visual C++ and it gives  *cannot convert from 'const float' to 'float &* error.

```
T& GetElement(size_t x) const {
    return _vector.at(x);
}
```

GetElement is a method, and _vector is a member variable.

Comment: cannot convert from 'const float' to 'float &' from Visual C++

Comment: Use `const T&`. Your method is const, and therefore _vector is const, and at() returns `const T&`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not compile because you are trying to return a non-constant reference to an element of the vector, which is itself `const`.

The reason the vector is `const` is that your member function is declared `const`:

```
T& GetElement(size_t x) const // <<== Here
```

This `const`-ness marker gets propagated to all members, including the `_vector`.

To fix this problem, add `const` to the type of the reference being returned ([demo](http://ideone.com/gk4bjP)).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't make a difference. Still the same error.

Comment: @jira This may have to do with the compiler then: the code compiles perfectly with Gnu's compiler (see link to the demo). If that's the compiler, am not sure how to get around that without a hack. Another suggestion might be changing the return type to `T` from `T&` - it shouldn't make a difference for `float`s and other primitives.

Comment: @jira If you are still getting the error after this change, you are likely trying to change the result:  `t.GetElement(0) += 1`.  If you want to be able to modify the elements, you need a non-const overload of this function as well.

Comment: Looks like I must have a load of these const related problems in my code. Whenever I change something some other error pops up somewhere else ... Anyway, I'm going to accept this answer as it addresses my original question

Answer (score 5):

You haven't shown your error, but as a guess, it looks like `_vector` is a member (from the `_` prefix you've given it) and you're in a `const` member function, so `at` will return a `const` reference. So you probably need:

```
const T& GetElement(size_t x) const {
    return _vector.at(x);
}
```